# Can we send the output of the Python script that is present in Jenkins job as mail after the Build is completed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins freestyle job, In the job I have a python script which does some operations and now I would like to send a mail through Jenkins with content as the output of the script. Please suggest me the possible ways to do this or any suggestions on the plugins available.

Answer (score 1):

there is an extended email option which would allow you to attach a file and email to you.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

[image]

You could output your python script to a specific log file and include with your build.log if need be.

hth

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution, I used a plugin in Jenkins or more like option called editable mail notification (can refer https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/ ) here I would like to add content of python script instead of $DEFAULT_CONTENT, Can that be done?